# Hasura querying becomes exponentially slower when two or more permission conditions are added

Tags: postgresql, authentication, permissions, hasura

With this custom check on select:

```
{
"_or": [
    {
        "user": {
            "id": {
                "_eq": "X-Hasura-User-Id"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "feed_item_access": {
            "community_allowed_view": {
                "_eq": true
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

The query takes 8 seconds, however if I remove either of the two checks in the OR the query goes down to 1 second.

it doesn't seem to matter what the conditional checks are, with one it's great as soon as there's two it grinds to a halt.

Worth noting this is only excrutiatingly slow when there is an authorisation header, but it doesn't seem to be related to that even if the permission check isn't looking for x-hasura-user-id it can be slow. For admin queries it's completely fine.

It seems to mostly happen when the permissions have to look at a related table and there's two of those permissions, even if they are looking in the same table:

```
{
    "_or": [
        {
            "feed_item_access": {
                "community_allowed_view": {
                    "_eq": true
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "feed_item_access": {
                "clinicians_allowed_view": {
                    "_eq": true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The above takes over 5 seconds to process, if I remove either of the conditions it drops below 1 second.

I should also add on my local docker build it's fine, the issue only presents itself on the hasura hosted environment.

Any ideas what I could be missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hasura's permissions system dynamically adds additional filter criteria onto the SQL statement that is generated and executed against your database. I don't think there is any overhead on the Hasura side of things that would cause multiple `OR` conditions to inherently be slower other than it's resulting in a less than optimal query plan once it hits your Database.

Can you share the query profile for this query with the permissions on and off so we can see whether or not adding indicies or any other DB performance tuning can help mitigate the issue?

If you want to be able to analyze the query with the permissions included you just need to add the `x-hasura-role` header in the console along with the admin secret and any other session related values that are considered during your permission evaluation. For example:

[image: hasura console headers]

Then when you click the `analyze` button the output from Hasura will include the full SQL that was generated including the permissions filters as well as the actual query plan against your database.

Do you have the same exact dataset in your local environment as what is in the database being managed by your Hasura cloud instance? The query plan and performance can vary quite a bit depending on the size of the data involved

Comment: hey thanks for your answer! what you say makes perfect sense although I don't understand why it's so slow on hasura.io but in my local docker it's blazing fast.

I'm not sure how to create a query profile, I assume that means to click the 'analyze' button ongraphiql and show what that is - however that only works when the admin secret is also passed in which seems to negate the permissions performance issue.

Any idea what I should be doing to get the query profile out?

Comment: @meds Updated my answer to show how you can analyze the query please update your question with the output of the query plan. It would be great if you could get the query plan from both your local environment as well as the cloud environment to see if the query planner is making different choices in the two environments

Comment: Looks like there's no need - I discovered while the fed item permissions were quite inocuous the way i was querying it was going through a more complex permissions scheme in a related parent object - I found out after doing the analysis you suggested and the query came back as a huuuuuge result (too big to put ina  stackoverflow post). I'm giving you the answer as you helped me diagnose the problem (didn't know I could emulate roles with headers like that), the solution is obviously going to be to trim down the 30,000+ character query but that's a topic for a different question.

Comment: @meds Glad that I could help out! I didn't realize for quite a while either that you could use the headers to better diagnose query patterns + permissions but its definitely an invaluable tool when building with Hasura

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify your PostgreSQL version, but if it's 12 (or newer) try disabling JIT mode.

Depending on how you run PostgreSQL, but if you are using Docker Compose, add the following to your PostgreSQL service definition:

```
command: postgres -c jit=off
```

Example:

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    command: postgres -c jit=off
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - /opt/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: Secure
```

See also this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/3672).

Comment: Thanks bro, you saved me!!!

```
postgres:
    image: postgis/postgis:15-3.3
    command: postgres -c jit=off
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
```